Images won't load
I'm working on a project and the user uploads their images (path is saved in MySQL) and the image itself is saved in a directory named uploads. I have my HTML CSS and JavaScript files stored in /var/www/html and my Node.js file in /var/www/example/server.js and my uploads directory in /var/www/example/uploads. I've been troubleshooting for hours and even asked chatgpt and I can't figure out what this issue is. I've tried changing the path, chmod 755, adding stuff to the Apache config and the .htaccess, and probably more. I verified that these images exist and that they load properly when adding them to a straight up HTML page. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The node server file and the uploads directory are both stored in the same directory. But I still keep getting this error in console:
GET https://example.com/uploads/images[]-1719563588934-59855315.jpg 404 (Not Found)

This is the path it shows me in the inspect element HTML:
<img src="/uploads/images[]-1719563589026-954829461.png" alt="Item Image" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

I've been troubleshooting for hours and even asked chatgpt and I can't figure out what this issue is. I've tried changing the path, chmod 755, adding stuff to the Apache config and the .htaccess, and probably more. I verified that these images exist and that they load properly when adding them to a straight up HTML page. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The node server file and the uploads directory are both stored in the same directory.

Do the iimage files actually have [] in their names?

Yes the image file names actually contain the [] brackets. It’s just how I formatted the images to be saved.

Try /example/uploads/... in the URL.

When you access them in a simple HTML page, what is the URL you use? The same URL should work in this project.

First, I would like to thank you for your quick replies.
When i go to example.com/example/uploads, i get a 404 not found. I could be wrong but I think this makes sense since the document root is /var/www/html and the images and server files are in /var/www/example.
When i accessed them in a simple HTML page, i just simply copied the image to /var/www/html and tagged it in the html page, not using any js

you need to include web server config: are you serving files with apache or node js? include the relevant part that serves images (so far I don't see how it has anything to do with node.js/express)

Hi, Is this issue still persisting ?

If they're loading properly when you hard-code the path in an HTML page, but not when that path is pulled from the database, you should check the database create/get functions. To make debugging easier you should insert some files with simple names so you can see discrepancies more easily (test.png is much more readable than 1108642662421.png).
Ensure that file extensions are being handled properly as well, and that you aren't appending extensions onto files that already have one, or storing them incorrectly.
Finally, try debugging the back-end and checking what path is being returned in the database call, and compare the full path that it's constructing with the actual path as you can verify it. Chances seem high that the path to file is simply not being constructed properly, whether that's in saving it or retrieving it.
